# Rails: Specify email account that mail_to will open

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mailto

I'm relatively new to Rails and would like to place a button on the admin-only part of my website that will open my company gmail account with the addresses of all of the registered users pre-populated in the 'bcc' field.

I *almost* have the mail_to helper working for this purpose *except* the mail_to link opens my personal gmail account instead of my company account.

Is there a way to use rails to trigger the log in to a specific gmail account and to pre-populate the "to" field as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think, the link opens your personal gmail account just because you have it open in another browser window or tab.

AFAIK, Gmail does not allow to open different accounts in different windows at the same time. (Probably I miss something.)

Therefore, to make link open your corp account regardless of everything, the link handler should forcibly log out the current Gmail session and start a new one.

I don't think that you really want this behaviour (I mean closing the current session in such a rude way).